# Recommendations for a reusable data table with pagination component in Angular 4/5

Tags: angular, frontend

What is the best practice here? `Material` version seems to be an overkill, I don't understand the code that implements it. 
On the other hand I am looking for something reusable across the whole app, as there are multiple tables with multiple data types.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't finalized a library yet, I suggest to take a look at [Datagrid component](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/datagrid/pagination) from [Project Clarity](http://clarity.design). It's a powerful component with loads of features, including pagination.

Answer (score 1):

For Tables, I would suggest simple go for a Shared Component containing Bootstrap grids with *ngFor loops.

```
<div class="row listview">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
         //CREATES TABLE HEADERS
            <tr class="table-head-color">
              <th *ngFor="let columns of data?.display_columns; let i = index">
                {{ columns }}
                <br>
              </th>
            </tr>
            //THIS WILL CREATE CORRESPONDING DATA TO IT
            <tr *ngFor="let row1 of data?.row1; let i= index">
              <td style="white-space: nowrap" *ngFor="let columns of data?.display_columns; let i = index">
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="columns != 'someObject1'">{{ row1[columns] }}</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can reuse this and manipulate data as per convenience. I too looked at several libraries and seemed to be an overkill.
For simple data display, external libraries are good but when it comes to binding with events, confusion happens.
For pagination too, you can have a look at Bootstrap paginations.
If you want to display it in a certain way, you can very well write functions in Component.ts and bind them up with the HTML tags where you want to invoke them.
Hope this answers your question.